# How to configure tc server 4 in IntelliJ for debugging mode?

Tags: intellij-idea, tcserver

I'm working on a project using tc server 4 and I'm using IntelliJ as IDE. The application is running successfully in the server while I use the command line to start/stop server.

But I wanted to enable debugging mode in IntelliJ in case I need to put break points in Java files. The tc server plugin only support up to tc server 3 because version 4 has a huge difference in the folder structure and excutable scripts.

So can you please advise if is there a good way to configure tc server 4 in IntelliJ for debugging mode?

Answer (score 0):

Please [vote for the corresponding feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-218781).